How to solve the problem of type recognition error with enum type as key？
How to solve the problem of type recognition error with enum type as key？
I would like to keep the type hints；I would like to keep the type hints；I would like to keep the type hints；I would like to keep the type hints
type t1 = 
 Expect<Equal<PathValue<Props, 'bar.foo.baz'>, number>> // expect: true. yes, it's true

type t2 = 
 Expect<Equal<PathValue<Props, 'bar.width'>, string>>  // expect: true. no, it's false

This is an example of code:
    type IsAny<T> = unknown extends T
        ? [keyof T] extends [never]
            ? false
            : true
        : false;
    
    /* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
    export type PathImpl<T, Key extends keyof T> = Key extends string
        ? IsAny<T[Key]> extends true
            ? never
            : T[Key] extends Record<string, any>
              ?
                    | `${Key}.${PathImpl<T[Key], Exclude<keyof T[Key], keyof any[]>> & string}`
                    | `${Key}.${Exclude<keyof T[Key], keyof any[]> & string}`
              : never
        : never;
    /* eslint-enable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
    
    export type PathImpl2<T> = PathImpl<T, keyof T> | keyof T;
    
    export type Path<T> = keyof T extends string
        ? PathImpl2<T> extends infer P
            ? P extends string | keyof T
                ? P
                : keyof T
            : keyof T
        : never;
    
    export type PathValue<
        T,
        P extends Path<T>,
    > = P extends `${infer Key}.${infer Rest}`
        ? Key extends keyof T
            ? Rest extends Path<T[Key]>
                ? PathValue<T[Key], Rest>
                : never
            : never
        : P extends keyof T
          ? T[P]
          : never
    
    enum style {
      HEIGHT = 'height',
      WIDTH = 'width'
    }
    
    type Props = {
        foo: string;
        bar: {
            street: string;
            [style.HEIGHT]: string;
            [style.WIDTH]: string;
            foo: {
                baz: number;
            }
        };
    };
    
    declare function useProp<P extends Path<Props>>(path: P): PathValue<Props, P>;
    
    import type { Equal, Expect } from '@type-challenges/utils'
    
    type t1 = 
     Expect<Equal<PathValue<Props, 'bar.foo.baz'>, number>>
    
    type t2 = 
     Expect<Equal<PathValue<Props, 'bar.width'>, string>>

There is also another limitation in that I want to keep the type hints:


It seems to be a problem with PathValue and not a general TypeScript problem. It works without PathValue: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/KYOwrgtgBAzgLgTwDbCgbwFBSgCQKICSA4jgCpQC8UA5ABbACWA5rXNQDRZQDqBAIqRyUaAdwYATOLWoYAvhgyIADqgAKAJwD2SmMMzZsAM02aAXLDjqGIJgG4u2AEYBDdef0HP8dcGBxz3tZ2Dp5QANrwyMAAdPjEZAC6AZZB9qEGEYgo0bwCOEkWVjZp6VDGZughpVAuAF7m4BCOwOol6fKesvZdCgwQSprqcFDKqGhQeACOYM5I7BMAHioAxsOyZVrQ1AACowC0y7SzKDbAMAD0YHAMSDAyiggqIwCMwlh4S8CrADxTM0jfDTaGBhagudTUBKg8qQ0F1SHzRrNdQAPhR9geTzgACY3osVnBftNZoCtDo4a5YdQxJJpAl5oEbGj7EA

thanks for the effort. But the type passed in must be a string type like bar.foo.baz and bar.width

The problem is in line 36. In line 34, Rest extends Path<T[Key]> evaluates to false and line 36 returns never.

"But the type passed in must be a string type like bar.foo.baz and bar.width" This should be part of your question and not a comment. Otherwise, you'll get other answers.

The problem can be traced to this condition within the PathValue definition:
Rest extends Path<T[Key]>

In this case, Rest is string literal type "width" and Path<T[Key]> is enum value type style.WIDTH - and the condition fails.
The issue here is to do with how TypeScript's type hierarchy works. An enum value type is considered an extension of its literal value, but the opposite is not true. If you test it like this:
type DoesEnumExtendLiteral = style.WIDTH extends 'width' ? true : false;
type DoesLiteralExtendEnum = 'width' extends style.WIDTH ? true : false;

...you will find that DoesEnumExtendLiteral is true, but DoesLiteralExtendEnum will be false.
So what SHOULD you do? Well, to be honest... I'd probably abandon the use of enums in this case (i.e. specifically where they might need to be used as field names in this Path-building mechanism), and instead approximate it using other constructs. As ugly and repetitive as the following is, it's valid, and ends with a style that works in much the same way as an enum:
namespace style {
  export const HEIGHT = 'height';
  export type HEIGHT = typeof HEIGHT;
  export const WIDTH = 'width';
  export type WIDTH = typeof WIDTH;
}
type style = (
    | style.WIDTH
    | style.HEIGHT
);

I know this isn't ideal. If there's a better way, I'd like to know about it too.

It's really not ideal, but thanks for the reply, I honestly hate enumerations too, but have to use it

TypeScript enums are opaque or nominal. Meaning "width" is not the same as style.WIDTH.
One workaround is to map the enum value to a string using `${style.WIDTH}` and then use a mapped type:  [K in `${style.WIDTH}`]: string;
However, you'll notice this will lead to other problems. A mapped type may not declare additional properties. So you might want to wrap that enum key into another nested layer. For example:
type Props = {
  foo: string;
  bar: {
    street: string;
    [style.HEIGHT]: string;
    width: {
      [K in `${style.WIDTH}`]: string;
    };
    foo: {
      baz: number;
    };
  };
};


type t2 = Expect<Equal<PathValue<Props, `bar.width.${style.WIDTH}`>, string>>;

Another option is to avoid enums all the way and use a const object instead. Then you can do this:
const style = {
  HEIGHT: "height",
  WIDTH: "width",
} as const;

type Props = {
  foo: string;
  bar: {
    street: string;
    [style.HEIGHT]: string;
    [style.WIDTH]: string;
    foo: {
      baz: number;
    };
  };
};

type t2 = Expect<Equal<PathValue<Props, `bar.${typeof style.WIDTH}`>, string>>;


Thanks your reply. But there is also another limitation in that I want to keep the type hints(Already updated to the issue)

@jabaa Because that does not rely on any literal string type checks of PathToValue. It's just chained Indexed access types

I agree that sentence was misleading. I updated it. What I'm saying is that, PathToValue<Props, "bar.street"> returns string while indexing an enum key returns never because of the string type checks. Try it!

@jabaa We're going in circles. I've posted two ideas on how I'd solve this above :)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
